# Why aren't my examples showing up in GoDoc?

Tags: go, godoc

I created a package with examples in the _test.go file and it worked fine. I moved the examples to integration_test.go then example_test.go and now they don't show up in [my godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/patrobinson/gokini)

The contents of example_test.go is like so:

```
//+build integration

package gokini

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type PrintRecordConsumer struct {
    shardID string
}

func ExampleRecordConsumer() {
    // SNIP

    // Output:
    // Checkpointer initializing
    // foo
    // PrintRecordConsumer Shutdown
}
```

Comment: Why the build tag?

Comment: Yes, the build tag causes this file to be excluded unless you explicitly provide that build tag, which godoc.org surely does not.

Comment: Ah, the build tag is there because I wanted to remove the mocks from the example code so I had to make it an integration test

Comment: Thanks removing the build tag fixed it. I'd still like it to be an integration test but I guess I'll have to find another way

Comment: Try separating into a test package: "As with typical tests, examples are functions that reside in a package's _test.go files. Unlike normal test functions, though, example functions take no arguments and begin with the word Example instead of Test."

Comment: Just keep integration tests and examples in separate files.

Comment: I am, but still when you run `go test` the examples are run and fail